# Is it possible to wait for either button A or button B?

Tags: micropython, mit-scratch, bbc-microbit

This is code that waits for an event coming from button A.

`control.waitForEvent(Button.A, EventBusValue.MICROBIT_EVT_ANY)`

I want to wait for either button A OR button B to be pressed.

Is this possible?

*EDIT*

I know that in `Scratch` this is possible with something like `button.any`, also the above code is written in `microjavascript`, but it is written similarly in `micropython`, so maybe someone from this field can also help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I could do it was with common `function` for `A` nad `B`, to be called on events of button pressed, like:

```
input.onButtonPressed(Button.A, function () {
    qAndA(true)
})
input.onButtonPressed(Button.B, function () {
    qAndA(false)
})
```

The true and false are not the best implementations but to know which button was pressed, I needed to pass the `true` for `A` and `false` for B.

This was required in my case, because I was writing test and later in this function I would compare the button pressed and the actual correct answer. The function (without my full implementation) goes something like this:

```
function qAndA(aOrB: boolean) {
    if (text_list.length == 0) {
        basic.showNumber(count)
        basic.pause(2000)
        basic.showLeds(`
            # # # # #
            . . # . .
            . . # . .
            . . # . .
            . . # . .
            `)
    }
    if (text_list[0] == Q1 && aOrB == true) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the python code generated using the 'on event from' block in https://makecode.microbit.org. This block can be found under the Advanced tab. The block can be set to wait for either button A or B to be pressed. The micropython code generated in this case is:

```
control.on_event(EventBusSource.MICROBIT_ID_BUTTON_AB,
    EventBusValue.MICROBIT_EVT_ANY,
    on_microbit_id_button_ab_evt)
```

The equivalent JavaScript code can also be viewed in the editor.

Comment: What is `on_microbit_id_button_ab_evt`

Answer (score 0):

In scratch, placing a [Wait for <Key Pressed (a) ||or|| Key Pressed (b)>], will do the trick, you can just slot a key pressed (a) and a key pressed (b) into the same or statement, and place the new blocks into a "Wait until" block, place this where you want the code to stop and continue on the keypress update and you're golden.